# Is this wet venting solution ok?

Tags: bathroom, drain, drainage, drain-waste-vent

I am completely redoing my basement bathroom and am wondering if this way of venting the plumbing is ok. From what I've seen, wet venting is the most money and time efficient way to do it, so I would like to go that route if I can. I found this picture online of how to do a wet vent (http://www.jaytechplumbing.com/2013/01/wet-venting/), and option 2 seems to match my situation the most.

I drew up a quick picture of my idea of how to map this idea to my bathroom, see the picture, and am hoping that it will work the same as the picture that I found.

Could anyone confirm this solution for wet venting? Thank you.

[image]

[image]